# Convert List<Object> to List<CustomClass> in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have class:

```
public class BusinessUnit 
{
    private String name;

  //getter 
  //setter
}
```

I am getting `List<Object>` from service which I need to convert to `List<BusinessUnit>`. The data will be only name. But service is returning me Object. What is the best way to do this conversion in Java 8

Comment: Best thing is to adapt the service. List of `Object` is really not the best way to provide a service result.

Answer (score 5):

You mean :

```
List<Object> list = ...
List<BusinessUnit> result = list.stream()
        .map(name -> new BusinessUnit((String) name))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I assume you have a constructor in `BusinessUnit` which take a neme :

```
public class BusinessUnit {
    private String name;

    public BusinessUnit(){}

    public BusinessUnit(String name){
       this.name = name;
    }

    //getter 
    //setter
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that all elements are `String`, you could cast the result of the service to a `List<String>` :

```
List<String> list = (List<String>) service.getData(...);
```

And you should also try to change the service code to make it declare `List<String>` rather than a raw List : `List` or a `List<Object>`
In this way you could map `String` to `BusinessUnit` straightly :

```
List<BusinessUnit> businessUnits =
   list.stream()
       .map(BusinessUnit::new)
       .collect(Collectors.toList));
```

Where `BusinessUnit::new` is a `BusinessUnit` constructor that accepts a `String` as in the very good answer of @YCF_L.

But if some elements may not be `String` objects and that you want to exclude them (and why not logging the information), you should do things differently.

In this case, keeping `List<Object>` is not an option :

```
List<Object> list = service.getData(...);
```

You should filter elements that don't fit your requirements. For example here I remove `null` and not `String` objects :

```
List<BusinessUnit> businessUnits =
   list.stream()           
       .map(o -> {
                if (!(o instanceof String)){ 
                   logger.warn(o + "is not a String or is null"); 
                   return null;
                 }
                 return (String) o;
            }
        )
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .collect(Collectors.toList));
```

Comment: Thanks YCF :) No, there is not any trick or magic :) I just did the cast of the List before instead of making it during the stream processing. We were downvoted ! As usually you will answer me :)

Comment: From `Object` to `String` here : `.map(name -> new BusinessUnit((String) name))`.

Comment: my bad I copied the code of the other answer not my answer yes I meant `.map(name -> new BusinessUnit((String) name))`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<BusinessUnit> units = list.stream().map(BusinessUnit.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's the best way if you are sure, that object is BusinessUnit, or esle you can create your cast method, and check there, that `object instanceof BusinessUnit` and so on..

cast is method in Class.java

if some object is String you can also

```
List<A> a = `list.stream().map(String.class::cast).map(BusinessUnit::new).collect(Collectors.toList());`
```

Of course, you should have single BusinessUnit constructor that accepted one String.

For this instance `BusinessUnit::new` or else you can write something like this

```
.map(s -> new BusinessUnit(...))
```

**updated**

You also can filter your list of objects, `filter(String.class::isInstance)`, and then use map.

Have a look at Class.java methods,  there are many interesting and useful methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because your service isn't returning Strings, you have to loop through the list and convert them to your BusinessUnit class

```
List<BusinessUnit> businessUnits = list.stream()
.map(object -> new BusinessUnit(object.toString()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In your BusinessUnit class update your constructor method

```
public BusinessUnit(String object){
this.name = object;
}
```

I hope this works

Comment: It doesn’t compile

Comment: I have a class Weather that has Map<String, Object> coordinates as it's instance variable

Now, I will get List<Weather> from service. I need to return certain dostinct coordinates values and assign to List<CustomClass>
For ex. 
weather.stream.filter(a - > a. getId.equals(id).
After the filter method I need to get a certain coordinate by its key(which I know) and use distinct function and assign these values to List<CustomClass>. CustomClass has only String name as its instance variable and coordinate value will be Object type but stored as text

What is the best way to do this in Java8

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by Java 8 Stream concept:

```
List<BusinessUnit> units = businessUnitsAsObjects.stream()
    .map(BusinessUnit.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```